# Convert one column to specific number of columns

Tags: python, numpy, bigdata

I'm trying to convert one column of data which has values in `range(0,5)` to 6 columns according to their value.
For example if its value is 0 the first column of those six one becomes one and other become 0 and so on.However since the shape of my target is (1034892, 1) it takes a lot of time and even sometime it crashes. This code has worked for 500000 of data but for this amount it does not.

Is there any way to make it possible for this amount of data?

```
def convert_to_num_class(target):
    for i, value in enumerate(target):
        if i ==0:
            y_new =np.array( np.eye(6)[int(value[0])])
        else:
            y_new = np.vstack((y_new, np.eye(6)[int(value[0])]))
    return(y_new)
```

Comment: Sounds like a home-brew version of sklearn's [One-Hot Encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). Using the built-in has many optimization benefits

Comment: @martineau yes it could be possible. many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pandas `get_dummies`:

```
>>> target = np.random.randint(6, size=(10, 1))  # the original target is of shape (1034892, 1)
>>> target = target.flatten()
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 3, 1, 5, 4, 5])

>>> pd.get_dummies(target).to_numpy()
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

In case your target doesn't have all the values in the range you want (as in the above example where `target` doesn't have the value 2), there will be missing columns for that missing values. One workaround is the following:

```
>>> target = pd.Categorical(target, categories=np.arange(6))

>>> pd.get_dummies(target).to_numpy()
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

It is very fast even for `target` of size `(1034892, 1)` that you have.

Comment: this is an error that I've got when use it. Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: @pgol I have updated my unswer. You just have to flatten your `target` (assuming that it is a numpy array of shape (1034892, 1)).

Answer (score 0):

I also have solved it by using to_categorical of keras.utils.np_utils and it takes just a second for this amount of data:

```
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
def convert_to_num_class(target):
target = target.astype(np.int)
return(to_categorical(target, len(np.unique(target))))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to resort to `pandas` or `keras`, just index using a tuple:

```
import numpy as np

categories = 6
N = 10
target = np.random.randint(categories, size=(N,1)) # this should be your data

y = np.zeros((N, categories), dtype=np.uint8)
mask = (np.arange(N), target.flatten())
y[mask] = 1
```

Performance check:

```
def one_hot(target, categories=None): 
    target = target.flatten() 
    N = target.size 
    if categories is None:
        categories = target.max() - target.min() + 1 
    y = np.zeros((N, categories), dtype=np.uint8) 
    mask = (np.arange(N), target) 
    y[mask] = 1 
    return y 

N = 1034892
cats = 6
r = np.random.randint(cats, size=(N))

%timeit one_hot(r)
# 9.63 ms ± 187 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

import pandas as pd
%timeit pd.get_dummies(r).to_numpy()
# 18.2 ms ± 183 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: I did it but it still takes a lot of time for this amount of data.

Comment: It was basically instant on my machine with 1034892 values.